# IDXGISwapChain::Present Memory Leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, directx, direct3d

I'm kinda learning Direct3D and have this quite basic code, nothing too fancy. During debugging in Visual Studio I noticed a [constantly increasing memory usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvHal.jpg), which is kinda weird.

From what I observed, `IDXGISwapChain::Present` allocates new memory blocks with each frame update. [Here is a difference between two memory snapshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXubu.jpg), about 7 second difference.

I have no idea what could be the cause of this, maybe I forgot to call some sort of clearing function? And I don't even have any buffers or shaders or anything like that, just basic init stuff. I really would like to know how can I possibly fix this. Here's the entire code:

```
//==============================================================================
// main.cpp
// Copyright (c) Michael Loda. All rights reserved.
//==============================================================================

#if defined(DEBUG) || defined(_DEBUG)
#define ALC_DEBUG 1
#else
#define ALC_DEBUG 0
#endif


#include <crtdbg.h>

#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0601
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>
#include <ShlObj.h>
#include <comdef.h>
#include <wrl.h>

#include <d3d11.h>
#include <DirectXMath.h>
#include <DirectXColors.h>


using Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr;


HWND g_WindowHandle = NULL;
LPCSTR g_WindowClassName = "WindowClass";

ComPtr<ID3D11Device> g_D3DDevice;
ComPtr<ID3D11DeviceContext> g_D3DDeviceContext;
ComPtr<IDXGISwapChain> g_D3DSwapChain;
ComPtr<ID3D11RenderTargetView> g_D3DRenderTargetView;
ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> g_D3DDepthStencil;
ComPtr<ID3D11DepthStencilView> g_D3DDepthStencilView;


LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND p_Window, UINT p_Msg, WPARAM p_WParam, LPARAM p_LParam);


int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE p_Inst, HINSTANCE, LPSTR p_CmdLine, int p_Show)
{

#if ALC_DEBUG
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
#endif

    if (FAILED(CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINITBASE_MULTITHREADED)))
        return 1;



    HRESULT _Result = S_OK;


    UINT _DeviceFlags = D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT;

#if ALC_DEBUG
    _DeviceFlags |= D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
#endif

    if (FAILED(_Result = D3D11CreateDevice(NULL, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, NULL, _DeviceFlags, NULL, 0, D3D11_SDK_VERSION, g_D3DDevice.GetAddressOf(), NULL, g_D3DDeviceContext.GetAddressOf())))
        throw _Result; // TODO: Handle

#if ALC_DEBUG
    ComPtr<ID3D11Debug> _D3DDebug;
    if (FAILED(_Result = g_D3DDevice->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(_D3DDebug.GetAddressOf()))))
        throw _com_error(_Result); // TODO: Handle
#endif

    WNDCLASSEXA _WindowClass = {};
    _WindowClass.cbSize = sizeof(_WindowClass);
    _WindowClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;
    _WindowClass.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    _WindowClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    _WindowClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    _WindowClass.hInstance = p_Inst;
    _WindowClass.hIcon = LoadIconA(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    _WindowClass.hCursor = LoadCursorA(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    _WindowClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);
    _WindowClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    _WindowClass.lpszClassName = g_WindowClassName;
    _WindowClass.hIconSm = LoadIconA(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if (!RegisterClassExA(&_WindowClass))
        throw; // TODO: Handle

    g_WindowHandle = CreateWindowExA(0, g_WindowClassName, "", WS_POPUP, 0, 0, 1280, 720, NULL, NULL, p_Inst, NULL);
    if (!g_WindowHandle)
        throw; // TODO: Handle


    {
        ComPtr<IDXGIDevice> _DXGIDevice;
        if (FAILED(_Result = g_D3DDevice->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(_DXGIDevice.GetAddressOf()))))
            throw _Result; // TODO: Handle

        ComPtr<IDXGIAdapter> _DXGIAdapter;
        if (FAILED(_Result = _DXGIDevice->GetAdapter(_DXGIAdapter.GetAddressOf())))
            throw _Result; // TODO: Handle
        _DXGIDevice.Reset();

        ComPtr<IDXGIFactory> _DXGIFactory;
        if (FAILED(_Result = _DXGIAdapter->GetParent(IID_PPV_ARGS(_DXGIFactory.GetAddressOf()))))
            throw _Result; // TODO: Handle
        _DXGIAdapter.Reset();


        DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC _SwapChainDesc = {};
        _SwapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Width = 1280; // TODO: Change
        _SwapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Height = 720; // TODO: Change
        _SwapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60; // TODO: Change
        _SwapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
        _SwapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM; // TODO: SRGB?
        _SwapChainDesc.BufferDesc.ScanlineOrdering = DXGI_MODE_SCANLINE_ORDER_UNSPECIFIED;
        _SwapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Scaling = DXGI_MODE_SCALING_STRETCHED;
        _SwapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1; // TODO: Change
        _SwapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0; // TODO: Change
        _SwapChainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
        _SwapChainDesc.BufferCount = 1;
        _SwapChainDesc.OutputWindow = g_WindowHandle;
        _SwapChainDesc.Windowed = TRUE; // TODO: Fullscreen support
        _SwapChainDesc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;
        _SwapChainDesc.Flags = DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH;

        if (FAILED(_Result = _DXGIFactory->CreateSwapChain(g_D3DDevice.Get(), &_SwapChainDesc, g_D3DSwapChain.GetAddressOf())))
            throw _Result; // TODO: Handle


        if (FAILED(_Result = _DXGIFactory->MakeWindowAssociation(g_WindowHandle, DXGI_MWA_NO_ALT_ENTER)))
            throw _Result; // TODO: Handle


        _DXGIFactory.Reset();
    }

    {
        ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> _BackBuffer;
        if (FAILED(_Result = g_D3DSwapChain->GetBuffer(0, IID_PPV_ARGS(_BackBuffer.GetAddressOf()))))
            throw _Result; // TODO: Handle

        if (FAILED(_Result = g_D3DDevice->CreateRenderTargetView(_BackBuffer.Get(), NULL, g_D3DRenderTargetView.GetAddressOf())))
            throw _Result; // TODO: Handle
        _BackBuffer.Reset();


        D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC _Tex2DDesc = {};
        _Tex2DDesc.Width = 1280; // TODO: Change
        _Tex2DDesc.Height = 720; // TODO: Change
        _Tex2DDesc.MipLevels = 1;
        _Tex2DDesc.ArraySize = 1;
        _Tex2DDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
        _Tex2DDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
        _Tex2DDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
        _Tex2DDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
        _Tex2DDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
        _Tex2DDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
        _Tex2DDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

        if (FAILED(_Result = g_D3DDevice->CreateTexture2D(&_Tex2DDesc, NULL, g_D3DDepthStencil.GetAddressOf())))
            throw _Result; // TODO: Handle


        D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC _DSVDesc = {};
        _DSVDesc.Format = _Tex2DDesc.Format;
        _DSVDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
        _DSVDesc.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;
        _DSVDesc.Flags = 0;

        if (FAILED(_Result = g_D3DDevice->CreateDepthStencilView(g_D3DDepthStencil.Get(), &_DSVDesc, g_D3DDepthStencilView.GetAddressOf())))
            throw _Result; // TODO: Handle


        g_D3DDeviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, g_D3DRenderTargetView.GetAddressOf(), g_D3DDepthStencilView.Get());

        D3D11_VIEWPORT _Viewport = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1280.0f, 720.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }; // TODO: Change
        g_D3DDeviceContext->RSSetViewports(1, &_Viewport);

    }


    ShowWindow(g_WindowHandle, p_Show);





    MSG _Msg = {};
    while (_Msg.message != WM_QUIT)
    {
        if (PeekMessageA(&_Msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) != 0)
        {
            TranslateMessage(&_Msg);
            DispatchMessageA(&_Msg);
        }
        else
        {

            g_D3DDeviceContext->ClearRenderTargetView(g_D3DRenderTargetView.Get(), DirectX::Colors::MidnightBlue);
            g_D3DDeviceContext->ClearDepthStencilView(g_D3DDepthStencilView.Get(), D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH | D3D11_CLEAR_STENCIL, 1.0f, 0);

            _Result = g_D3DSwapChain->Present(1, 0);
            if ((_Result == DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_REMOVED) || (_Result == DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_RESET))
            {
                // TODO: On device removed
            }
            else
            {
                if (FAILED(_Result))
                    throw _Result; // TODO: Handle
            }

        }
    }


    g_D3DDeviceContext->ClearState();

    g_D3DDepthStencilView.Reset();
    g_D3DDepthStencil.Reset();
    g_D3DRenderTargetView.Reset();
    g_D3DSwapChain.Reset();

    g_WindowHandle = NULL;

    UnregisterClassA(g_WindowClassName, p_Inst);

    g_D3DDeviceContext.Reset();
    g_D3DDevice.Reset();

#if ALC_DEBUG
    _D3DDebug->ReportLiveDeviceObjects(D3D11_RLDO_DETAIL);
    _D3DDebug.Reset();
#endif

    CoUninitialize();

    return (int)_Msg.wParam;
}


LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND p_Window, UINT p_Msg, WPARAM p_WParam, LPARAM p_LParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT _PaintStruct = {};
    HDC _DC = NULL;

    switch (p_Msg)
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        }
        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            _DC = BeginPaint(p_Window, &_PaintStruct);
            EndPaint(p_Window, &_PaintStruct);
            return 0;
        }
        case WM_CLOSE:
        {
            // TODO: Improve this
            if (MessageBoxA(p_Window, "Are you sure you want to quit?", "", MB_YESNO | MB_ICONQUESTION) == IDYES)
                break;

            return 0;
        }
        default:
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return DefWindowProcA(p_Window, p_Msg, p_WParam, p_LParam);
}
```

Edit: I thought I would mention that when I turn off VSync (that is passing number 0 instead of 1 to Present function), the increasing memory usage is much higher and faster.

Comment: If this happens in debug more then it should be nothing to worry about.

Comment: @VTT It's happening also in Release build. I've tried already many things myself. Programming is all about solving problems after all. But well... I can't continue to write more code with such a problem. The more stuff I will be rendering, I'm sure the leak will be larger

Comment: You can try wrapping `#include <crtdbg.h>` into `#if ALC_DEBUG` block so it won't bring debug stuff into scope in release build.

Comment: @VTT Oh, that's actually a useful tip, haven't thought about that, thanks! It doesn't fix the problem though

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce stated behavior. On my configuration (VS2017 Win10 pro NVidia gfx) presented code does not perform any allocations at all while rendering even in debug mode. Maybe it is an issue with your system or driver or antivirus software or something else.

Comment: @VTT That is of course also possible. Maybe I'll try to update my GPU drivers. Those increasing changes are also quite small so you maybe could miss that, just saying

Comment: I've took two snapshots with 20 seconds interval and they show "no increase" for memory allocations (still 3841).

Comment: Another suggestion: switch to use only `W` versions of functions, `A` variants mostly exist only for compatibility with Win95. `BeginPaint - EndPaint` calls can be replaced with a single call to `ValidateRect` and you may also want to handle `WM_ERASE` returning `TRUE` so there will be less possibility of GDI interop.

Comment: @VTT I'll definitely try this out, after GPU drives updating is done. Is the whole thing with 'WM_PAINT' even necessary for D3D? Many tutorials include it but it seems fine without it

Comment: Handling `WM_PAINT` and `WM_ERASE` is definitely necessary.

Comment: You mean `WM_ERASEBKGND`? `WM_ERASE` doesn't seem to exist at all

Comment: Right, 'WM_ERASEBKGND`.

Comment: @VTT Ok. So as I said in the answer here, updating GPU drivers completely fixed everything. Thank you for help here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating my AMD Radeon R9 M375 drivers from 17.6.2 to 17.10.3 fixed the issue!