# DirectX Memory Leak Caused By SwapChain Present

Tags: memory-leaks, directx, directx-11

[Image of SwapChain Memory Leak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXEzz.png)

Hello, I'm just beginner of DirectX 11 programming,
but recently I faced a serious problem for me.
Even when I use any tutorials from Internet, some leaks always left.
I tracked it down what does cause it, and it was Swapchain Present.
But odd thing is, its not constantly increasing leak, but just one time.
And Its not even when Present is called at first time.
After few seconds, about 3~5mb memory increase like that image.
If I terminate program early, the leak doesnt get left.
Even its after when I see the screen drawed by Present function.
Its not critical for proceeding programming but its bugging me crazy.
After I searched some, I think it's about swap chain.
I can see the warning that suggests me
DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_DISCARD instead of DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD.
So I changed the Desc and increased buffercount to 2, but leak was still there. I tested on other computers but it was fine. I think recent Windows update is problem. I found a post but it was not my case. [IDXGISwapChain::Present Memory Leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47240121/idxgiswapchainpresent-memory-leak)
Its continuously increasing memory and his GPU is AMD, while mine was NVIDIA.
I tried reinstalling Windows, but its fine in few hours, but it comes out again.
Doesnt anyone suffer from this problem? I cant find any issue about this.
Please help me if somebody knows about this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

GUYS it was because of Nahimic.
Its the audio program you get suggested if you are using MSI laptop.
Dont install it.